# How to insert bulk record

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, api, lambda

I am working on API development using AWS API getaway and lambda.
I am using Serverless MySQL https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-mysql package for mysql connection and operation.

but I am unable to insert multiple records. If I pass the array of records to insert function it only insert single records.

Please suggest me how would I insert multiple records without using loop.

```
values=[
  [
    "229",
    25,
    "objective",
    [
      "49"
    ],
    "2019-07-24 08:59:39",
    "2019-07-24 08:59:39"
  ],
  [
    "229",
    26,
    "descriptive",
    [
      "Yes i have long term illness that limits my daily activities. Test..."
    ],
    "2019-07-24 08:59:39",
    "2019-07-24 08:59:39"
  ]
];
var sql = 'INSERT INTO `answers` (`user_id`, `question_id`, `question_type`, `answer`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)  VALUES (?)';

await connection.query(sql, values);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used this package before, but just going through the documentation, it doesn't seems that it provides additional capability to `batch` insert. So I think you still need to compose the query as you normally do batch insert for mysql.

`INSERT INTO table_name (field1,field2,field3) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply!.. I will check and let you know

Answer (score 1):

The batch mode is not available in this one. So if you want to avoid the loop one option is to compose the query as shown in one answer:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (field1,field2) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6);
```

But the better way to do is create a separate lambda function to insert the values by passing sequentially. It will give you more flexibility to insert values across.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/create-user-defined-function.html